# How to make API only accesible from a specific domain

Tags: node.js, express

Kinda new to NodeJS and Express, but I wanted to know how to secure an API endpoint without a login. It's a web3 application and all I have from the user is it's public address. Not working with jwt and authentication here.

I have an API with an endpoint "/claim". I only want the front-end client: "https://my-website.com" to be able to make the call to /claim. I can do that with cors and only allow the origin "https://my-website.com" but this doesn't stop direct https calls to my API.

Someone that knows the URL of my API can simply open up postman and send requests from there (or directly in the browser). How do I stop someone from directly calling the route?

Comment: You just can't. Anyone can inspect the network call in the browser and replicate it elsewhere.

Comment: You may check the `Referer`, but then it can be spoofed. Someone with enough knowledge can still directly call the route.

Comment: Hmm so it can't be solved. The API send a transaction that gives the caller some crypto ($0.05). But I don''t want it to be exploited. I limited that 1 address can claim once but someone could write a bot creating infinite wallets that claim. Perhaps a rate limiter? (2 calls from the same IP per week) Then someone could also still keep switching IPs but it would be cumbersome?

Comment: perhaps client certs are an option

Answer (score 0):

In your api you can also check the host, protocol, originalUrl using req object like :

`req.originalUrl ==> /claim`

`req.get('host') ==> my-website.com`

`req.protocol ==> https: or http`

```
if(req.get('host') == "my-website.com"){
    Your api code....
}else{
    send response like you are unauthorized..   
}
```

With above code you can protect your api as per host name..